# Template not updating and $http not firing requests when using custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a custom directive to handle a paste event and this is what I've come up with:

```
app.directive('ngPaste', function(){
    var obj = {
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            return function(scope, elem, attrs){
                elem.bind('paste', function() {
                    var funcName = attrs.ngPaste.replace('(', '').replace(')', '');
                    if(typeof(scope[funcName]) == 'function') {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            scope.$apply(scope[funcName]);
                        }, 10);
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    };
    return obj;
});
```

The problem is that the models that I change on the callback don't update the template and the $http object does not fire any request. I must be missing something really simple but, unfortunately, the docs are quite lacking on theses matters.

How can I solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: There's no $http request in your code. Did you check that everything - compile function, binding, etc. in your directive is being called (using `console.info`)?

Comment: I'm justs starting with angularjs and I know very little of it's pipeline. The function that i specify in ng-paste is successfully called, however, it seems that inside that function angular is "dead". There are no errors, the $http object is there but it simply does not work. No errors, no messages, nothing.

Comment: The same happens when trying to update a model. I update a model just as I would in a ng-change but the template is never updated.

Comment: can you offer a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using angular 1.1.4 which is unstable. I downgraded to 1.1.1 (which is also unstable but has functionality that I need) and the problem doesn't happen anymore.